# JavaScript for loop of strings in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

How to `document.write()` String from array, using for loop that will check if the checkboxes are selected. My example down isn't working. It works manually without for loop, so I assume that the problem is in loop.

```
<div style="width:100%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></div>
<div style="width:100%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></div>
<div style="width:100%"><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></div>
<div style="width:100%"><input type="submit" id="execute" value="Execute" onClick="run();"></div>
```

**submit.js**

```
function run() {
    myArr = [" ","You selected first checkbox", "You selected second checkbox", "You selected the last one"];

    snip = "<div>HERE GOES YOUR CHECKBOX CHOICE: </div>";

    for(m=1;m<4;m++) {
    if(document.getElementById("cb[m]").checked == true) {
        snip += "<br/> - " + myArr[m];
    }
    document.write(snip);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that once the current document has been loaded, any subsequent `document.write()` statements will clear the current document and start a new empty document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m` should be concatinated like `("cb" + m)` not `("cb[m]")`

***Should be :***

```
if(document.getElementById("cb" + m).checked == true) {
```

***Instead of :***

```
if(document.getElementById("cb[m]").checked == true) {
```

I think you want to write this statement from outside of for loop

```
document.write(snip);
```

**Suggestion**

Also you can use `innerHTML` instead of `document.write()` as its clear other content after loaded the document.

`innerHTML` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4wXh/)